# Finite sets are residual in the Hausdorff space

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, set-valued-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space, let $\mathbb{H}(X)$ denote the set of non-empty closed subsets of $X$ with [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) which we denote by $d_{\mathbb{H}(X)}$, and let $\mathbb{H}_{\operatorname{fin}}(X)$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{H}(X)$ consisting of non-empty finite sets.

---

If $X$ is finite then clearly $\mathbb{H}(X)=\mathbb{H}_{\operatorname{fin}}(X)$.  Moreover, a previous post, YCor pointed out that, in general, $\mathbb{H}_{\operatorname{fin}}(X)$ is dense in $(\mathbb{H}(X),d_{\mathbb{H}(X)})$ *(see this MSE post [for a short and simple proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123789/finite-sets-are-dense-with-respect-to-hausdorff-distance)).*

The discussion below the first linked post inspired the following "coupled questions":

- Is $\mathbb{H}_{\operatorname{fin}}(X)$ ever residual in $X$, when $X$ is infinite?
- *If not:* Is there a "standard" (weaker) topology on $\mathbb{H}(X)$ for which $\mathbb{H}_{\operatorname{fin}}(X)$ is residual

Comment: The set of nonempty finite subsets of cardinal $\le n$ is closed. Moreover, if $X$ has no isolated point, then it has empty interior. Hence if $X$ has no isolated point, the set of nonempty finite subsets is an $F_\sigma$ of empty interior (i.e., the complement of a $G_\delta$-dense subset, i.e., of a residual subset). So it's not residual (for $X$ nonempty with no isolated point).

Comment: @YCor I also modified the post to further ask, if there is a "typical/standard" topology on $\mathbb{H}(X)$ for which the collection of finite sets is residual?

Comment: The hyperspace of finite subset is dense in the hyperspace of compact subsets but not in the hyperspace of all closed sets (because the latter is not separable for non-compact $X$).