# Are Hölder functions between Banach spaces residual in the compact-open topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, banach-spaces, metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $C(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ equipped with the topology of [uniform convergence on compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence) [(i.e. the compact-open topology)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact-open+topology).  Consider the sub-collection $C^{\star}(X,Y)$ consisting of all $f\in C(X,Y)$ which are $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for some $\alpha \in (0,1]$.

Consider the two-part question:

- Is $C^{\star}(X,Y)$ dense in $C(X,Y)$?
- If so, is $C^{\star}(X,Y)$ generic (in the sense of Baire-Category; i.e. residual) in $C(X,Y)$ for the compact-open topology?

---

*Thoughts:* If $X$ and $Y$ both have the [BAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property), then the first point should be true (no idea about the second point), but I would prefer not to assume this.

Comment: C*(X,Y) is a countable union of closed sets with empty interior. (Also note that the compact open topology on C(X,Y) is not metrizable in general).

Comment: And if i'm not wrong, even "Lipschitz maps with range in finite dimensional subspaces" are a dense subset of C(X,Y) wrto the c.o. topology.

Comment: @PietroMajer Would you happen to have a reference to this last fact?

Comment: You seem to ask many similar questions ("is P residual in Q" where in most cases the answer is strongly negative since the complement of P is residual). In any case here you have a subspace of a space. A proper subspace of a Hausdorff topological space is never residual, since it's disjoint to some of its translates.

Comment: You've been asking 4 questions in less than 24h https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424645/finite-sets-are-residual-in-the-hausdorff-space, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424670/, now-deleted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424630/. I'd recommend to more thoroughly think about them before posting.

Comment: @YCor Fair I will do this; or (next time) update any question accordingly.  Thanks YCor for the tip.